# How do I open the Recovery Console for Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, boot-camp, recovery-console

I'm running BootCamp on my mac but the MBR needs fixing and I get this when I put in the XP disc:

[image]

A screen should appear giving me the Install or Repair option, but the Repair option is missing. It wants me to format everything before I start. How can I access the Recovery Console in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You are upfront for one extra step. At the previous step, `press R` to enter the recovery console, not `ENTER` to enter Windows XP setup page. Please reboot and try again.

[image: Example screen]

Comment: Yep, that's the screen I should be getting, but it takes me directly to this screen... As you can see, ENTER is an option here, so I haven't chosen to install yet. In fact, trying to install gives you an immediate warning that you must format since the MBR is screwed.